# Iterate list of ids and combination of match qyery

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j,
I have (s:Student)-[:Learn]-(c:Course). course contains a property called ids populated with list(ids=[123,456,789]). I would like to find batches with course ids.

Like, I have (s)-[:Belongs_To]-(batch{id=c.id}),(s)-[:Belongs_To]-(batch{id=c.id}),(s)-[:Belongs_To]-(batch{id=c.id}),... Here c.id is [123,456,789]. For this I did try like this.

match (s:Student)-[:Learn]-(c:Course) with s,c.id as ids Return (i IN ids | match (s)-[:Belongs_To]-(b:Batch{id:i})) as batches. But I am not getting results. Is it right way to do that? or else please give me your suggestions on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Create and share your graph via http://console.neo4j.org.

Comment: I have created graph via http://console.neo4j.org/r/m0aarh

Comment: calling this URL just returns an error message due to invalid cypher. Use the share button to put your create statements and then the query in question.

Comment: Thanks for response, I got it.